# Powershell Script to filter computer names and check for group membership and save

Tags: powershell, dns

This is a really noob question; the purpose of the script is to sweep the domain for computers that begin with something.  Then to check the computers for group membership and give results for computers that are not part of a specific group.  And then email.  But this is where I am having an issue.  I am trying to get the information from my `if` statement into an email.  But for the sake of simplicity I just want the output it in a file for now.

Here is what I have:

```shell
# Load the Microsoft Active Directory Module
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

# Get a list of computers that begin with Funk
$Computers = Get-ADComputer -filter "name -like 'Funk*'" | ForEach-Object {$_.Name}

# Identify which computers do not have "XYZGroup" group
$Group = "XYZGroup"
$Groupname = (Get-ADGroup $Group).distinguishedName
ForEach ($adcomputer in ($computers))
{  
    If ((Get-ADComputer $adcomputer -Properties MemberOf | Select -ExpandProperty MemberOf) -notcontains $Groupname) 
    {      
        "Group is not present for $adcomputer"
    }  
}
```

As you can see I don't currently have anything in there to actually output the data.  Any input?  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good lord, you're making things hard on yourself. First, you're getting all those computers' objects twice. Don't do that, just don't discard all the useful info on the first query. Or better yet, filter the first query, and only get the computers you really wanted in the first place. Check this out:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$Group = "XYZGroup"
$Groupname = (Get-ADGroup $Group).distinguishedName
$Computers = Get-ADComputer -filter "name -like 'Funk*'" -Prop MemberOf| Where{$_.MemberOf -notcontains $Groupname}
$computers |Select -Expand Name|Out-File 'C:\Path\To\Output.txt'
ForEach($Computer in $Computers){
    Send-MailMessage -From Me@company.com -To Someone@company.com -Subject "Rogue Computer!" -Body "$Computer is not in $Groupname"
}
```

Now you'll need to tweak the send-mailmessage cmdlet line, but that sounds like it does everything you wanted it to.

**Edit:** Ok, to get all the computers you could do something like this:

```
$CompList = $computers.name -join ", "
```

That gives you 'Computer1, Computer2, Computer3' as a string. Or if you want one per line you could use

```
$CompList = $computers.name -join "`n"
```

That would result in a multi-line string like:

```
Computer1
Computer2
Computer3
```

The nice part about that is that when it comes to send your email you just do something like:

```
Send-MailMessage -To Somebody@example.com -from me@example.com -subject "Computers not in $groupname" -Body "$CompList"
```

and the body is just the list of computer names one per line for easy copy/paste or whatever.

Comment: Hmmm,  the output didn't seem to filter out the results that had the group.  It included every device that met the initial filter.

Comment: That's because I forgot to include the MemberOf property on my Get-ADComputer query. I updated the answer. Sorry, that was a stupid mistake on my part.

Comment: Because my brain is fried.  I am going to ask this.  Let's assume I want to send the entire output of just the names in a single name with out bothering with the text file.  (I could have just used Get-file and kept the code as is, but hey, I'll try to simplify).  I assume I would skip "foreach".  But best way to dump the list with just names?

Comment: One name per line, or comma separated?

Comment: One name per line would be just fine for my purposes

Comment: Now you have completely answered my question.  But, alas, I thought of some additional things, and - of course my lack of experience is shining!  
For -filter, I'd like to add additional filtering.  As in like, and not like.  I know it's simple, but go figure I am struggling with simple. 
Example:  To filter for name like 'funk*' but exclude 'funky*' and 'funk1*' with in those results.

Comment: That probably qualifies as another question for somebody to get credit for answering, but let's just get it out of the way. You can add things to the Where clause such as: `Where{$_.MemberOf -notcontains $Groupname -and $_.name -notlike "funky*" -and $_.name -notlike "funk1*"}` or if you want to get a little more fancy it could probably be done better with a RegEx match.

Answer (score 0):

So is the question how to output data into a file?

One of the ways is appending **>> filename.fileextension** to whatever you want to output

Heads up this will NOT overwrite the file entirely, it will append whatever it is you chose, to the  file's content.

For example:

```shell
# Load the Microsoft Active Directory Module
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

# Get a list of computers that begin with Funk
$Computers = Get-ADComputer -filter "name -like 'Funk*'" | ForEach-Object {$_.Name}

# Identify which computers do not have "XYZGroup" group
$Group = "XYZGroup"
$Groupname = (Get-ADGroup $Group).distinguishedName
ForEach ($adcomputer in ($computers))
{  If ((Get-ADComputer $adcomputer -Properties MemberOf | Select -ExpandProperty MemberOf) -notcontains $Groupname) 
    {      
       "Group is not present for $adcomputer" >> result.txt
    }  
}
```

Comment: Thank ya.  Alright cool.  I forgot about >>, and get that now, it records the result for each item and adds it to the text file.  The downside I noticed is that it works because >> does not overwrite the existing data.  The problem is that on recurrent runs it would just add to the existing data.
I realize I could just script it to delete the file if present at beginning of the script.  but I also know powershell can overwrite the existing data.

Comment: Yep you're right, I believe the Clear-Content commandlet would be great to solve that problem.

Comment: There's also a set-content which would overwrite the file with whatever content you like.